# VBScript - Get NTFS Compressed file's actual size

Tags: vbscript, ntfs, filesystemobject

I have noticed that the "size" property of an NTFS compressed file actually returns its uncompressed size and I can't seem to find a way to get the actual size on disk.

I would need this value in order to know the real weight of specific folders that contain compressed data.

Is there a way to do this in VBS ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you execute the same program without having to search for a file individually, using a "UserAccounts.CommonDialog" which isn't active in all OS's anymore, also, I cleaned up the code so it only displays the size on disk and not any other redundant info.

Enjoy.

```
Dim sFile : sFile = "C:\testenv\compressed\test.txt"
Dim oShell, oFSO, oEnv, oNet
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oEnv = oShell.Environment("Process")
Set oNet = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim sTempFile, aText, i, aInfo
sTempFile = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(oFSO.GetTempName)
oShell.Run "%comspec% /c compact " & Chr(34) & sFile & Chr(34) & " > " & Chr(34) & sTempFile & Chr(34), 0, True
aText = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile(sTempFile,1).ReadAll,vbCrLf)
If oFSO.FileExists(sTempFile) Then oFSO.DeleteFile sTempFile, True 
For i = 0 To UBound(aText)
    If InStr(aText(i),oFSO.GetBaseName(sFile)) Then
        aInfo = Split(Replace(aText(i),"=",":"), ":")
        If IsNumeric(Trim(aInfo(1))) Then
            WScript.Echo sFile & " : Size on Disk = " & FormatNumber(Trim(aInfo(1)), 0) & " bytes"
        End If
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done something similar to this and put in a function. I was actually looking for some more 'just vbs' way but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: I believe this line **Set oNet = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")** should look like **Set oNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")**, without *WScript*.

Comment: Thanks! I've made slite modification based on your answer for this topic: **How can I make Total Commander show actual size instead “size on disk” in the “size” column**  https://superuser.com/questions/615105/how-can-i-make-total-commander-show-actual-size-instead-size-on-disk-in-the-s/1331024#1331024

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COMPACT.EXE dos command to get the file size and size on disk.

```
Option Explicit
 Dim oShell, oFSO, oEnv, oNet
 Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set oEnv = oShell.Environment("Process")
 Set oNet = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
 Dim sFile, sTempFile, aText, i, aInfo
 sFile = fBrowseForFile
 sTempFile = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(oFSO.GetTempName)
 oShell.Run "%comspec% /c compact " & Chr(34) & sFile & Chr(34) & " > " & Chr(34) & sTempFile & Chr(34), 0, True
 aText = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile(sTempFile,1).ReadAll,VbCrLf)
 If oFSO.FileExists(sTempFile) Then oFSO.DeleteFile sTempFile, True 
 For i = 0 To UBound(aText)
 If InStr(aText(i),oFSO.GetBaseName(sFile)) Then
 aInfo = Split(Replace(aText(i),"=",":"), ":")
 WScript.Echo sFile & " : Size = " & Trim(aInfo(0))
 WScript.Echo sFile & " : Size on Disk = " & Trim(aInfo(1))
 End If 
 Next
 Function fBrowseForFile()
 Dim sBrowsePath, sBrowseFilter, oBrowseDialog
 sBrowsePath = "C:\"
 sBrowseFilter = "All Files|*.*"
 Set oBrowseDialog = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")
 oBrowseDialog.Filter = sBrowseFilter
 oBrowseDialog.InitialDir = sBrowsePath
 oBrowseDialog.Flags = &H80000 + &H4 + &H8
 oBrowseDialog.ShowOpen
 fBrowseForFile = oBrowseDialog.FileName
 End Function
```

I found this solution [here](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/FILE39S-SIZE-ON-DISK-m33044.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, i had found this solution already before posting but was looking for something that did not rely on an external binary.